# How can I set an attributedstring for a particular string an an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch

I have an array which passes a set of strings across into a tableViewController and then onto a detailViewController. I want to be able to change the attributes of the selected array on the final detailViewController. On the final detailViewController I have:

```
NSDictionary *redAttrs = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]};
NSDictionary *greenAttrs = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor greenColor]};
[_WhatString setAttributes:redAttrs range:NSMakeRange(6, 5)];
[_WhatString setAttributes:greenAttrs range:NSMakeRange(20, 5)];

_WhatString = _DetailModal[2];
_WhatLabel.attributedText = _WhatString;
```

Where `_DetailModal` is the array and the particular array item (The string I want to edit) is at position `[2]`. The editing will be the same for each of my array items so I do not need to worry about dynamically changing it. Should this code be on the final detailedViewController or should it be implemented when I first declare and specify the array?

Would this be the correct way to do it?
I'm getting an *'unrecognized selector sent to instance'* error when I attempt to get load the detailViewController page. What would be causing this?

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking.